# Restricting number of cores used

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to restrict the number of cores that a tf session uses but it's not working. This is how I'm initializing the session:

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                                        intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                                        use_per_session_threads=True))
```

The system has 12 cores / 24 threads, and I can see that 40-60% of them are being used at any given point in time. The system also has 8 GPUs, but I construct the whole graph with `tf.device('/cpu:0')`.

UPDATE: To clarify, the graph itself is a simple LSTM-RNN, that hews very closely to the examples in the tf source code. For completeness here's the full graph:

```
node_input  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [n_steps, batch_size, input_size],  name = 'input')
list_input  = [tf.reshape(i, (batch_size, input_size)) for i in tf.split(0, n_steps, node_input)]
node_target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [n_steps, batch_size, output_size], name = 'target')
node_target_flattened = tf.reshape(tf.transpose(node_target, perm = [1, 0, 2]), [-1, output_size])
node_max_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name = 'batch_max_length')
node_cell_initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1, 0.1) 
node_cell = LSTMCell(state_size, input_size, initializer = node_cell_initializer)  
node_initial_state = node_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
nodes_output, nodes_state = rnn(node_cell, 
                                list_input, 
                                initial_state = node_initial_state, 
                                sequence_length = node_max_length)
node_output_flattened = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, nodes_output), [-1, state_size])
node_softmax_w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([state_size, output_size]), name = 'softmax_w')
node_softmax_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_size]), name = 'softmax_b')
node_logit = tf.matmul(node_output_flattened, node_softmax_w) + node_softmax_b
node_cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(node_logit, node_target_flattened, name = 'cross_entropy')
node_loss = tf.reduce_mean(node_cross_entropy, name = 'loss')
node_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(node_loss)
node_op_initializer = tf.initialize_all_variables()
```

One important thing to note is that if the first time I call `tf.Session`, I pass in the appropriate parameters, then the session *does* only run on a single core. The problem is that in subsequent runs, I am unable to change the behavior, even though I use `use_per_session_threads` which is supposed to specifically allow for session-specific settings. I.e. even after I close the session using `sess.close()` and start a new one with new options, the original behavior remains unchanged unless I restart the python kernel (which is very costly because it takes it nearly an hour to load my data).

Comment: Are you using multiple sessions in parallel? What kind of stuff are you doing in your graph? I just did a quick test with some ops reading from queue in parallel and doing loops, and setting those flags had the effect of restricting to 1 core

Comment: I updated the entry with the graph and some further comments. I'm just using one session at a time.

Comment: are you using the  session with  `with tf.Session(..) as sess:` ?

Comment: No I'm assigning the `tf.Session(...)` to `sess`, as I write in the beginning of my question.

Answer (score 1):

`use_per_session_threads` will only affect the `inter_op_parallelism_threads` but not the `intra_op_parallelism_threads`. The `intra_op_parallelism_threads` will be used for the Eigen thread pool (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc)) which is always global, thus subsequent sessions will not influence this anymore.

Note that there are other TF functions which can also trigger the initialization of the Eigen thread pool, so it can happen that it's already initialized before you create the first `tf.Session`. One example is `tensorflow.python.client.device_lib.list_local_devices()`.

I solve this in a way that very early in my Python script, I create a dummy session with the appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow does an optimization where the first time a `DirectSession` is created it will create static thread pools which then will be reused. If you want to change this, specify multiple different thread pools in the [session_inter_op_thread_pool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L209) flag and specify which one you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

In tensorflow 2.3.2 I managed to limit cpus by using `psutils` lib.
I provided this the beginning of the function

```
pid = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
pid.cpu_affinity([0, 1])
```

The later call of `model.fit` utilized exactly 2 cpus